# Save linked objects Primary key value already exists Relationships

Tags: android, database, realm, android-database, realm-list

I have just started to use `RealmDB` and cannot figure out how to save linked object correctly, to implement a sort of `foreign key`

Here is my main `User` model.

```
public class UserModel extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    public Long id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public UserSettings userSettingsModel;
}
```

**UserSettings Model** is defined as follows.

```
public class UserSettingsModel extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;
    public String email;
    public RealmList<Car> cars;
}
```

And **Car** is a model itself.

```
public class Car extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;
    public String model;
}
```

The problem is that when I am trying to save `UserModel` it tries to recreate all objects assigned to it. So before I saving user model I have already creates some `Car` objects.

I don't need to create them, but to reference like the foreign key in SQL databases. And when I am retrieving a user from the database it should automatically load all related data by primary keys.

Is it possible to achieve such behavior using Realm ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a managed object using `realm.createObject(clazz, pkValue);` if it doesn't exist yet, then set it as value or add it to the RealmList that you get another managed object.

You can also create managed objects from unmanaged objects with `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` (if the object has a primary key).

> And when I am retrieving a user from the database it should automatically load all related data by primary keys.

The RealmList allows access to the related objects, and in fact, is also queryable by calling `.where()` on it. However, this is not based on primary keys. That feature is tracked under "computed fields".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. Solved this problem by using the `copyToRealmOrUpdate` method instead of `copyToRealm`.